# How can I implement both JWT and Basic authentication in Micronaut and bypass certain URLs with Basic Auth?

Tags: java, jwt, basic-authentication, micronaut

how can we add jwt and basic authentication simultaneously in micronaut

I have a requirement where some calls are authenticated with JWT/Filters and some call are authenticated with Basic Auth, I want that all the calls having /internal/ should bypass with basic auth and others calls  bypass with jwt authentication . Is it possible to have 2 web security configurer based on url or something? How we can achieve this?

I am able to exclude specific url from JWT authentication but how can I ask micronout to go for basic auth?

Comment: What happens when you add support for both basic auth and JWT in your app?

Comment: i think that might be possible by adding a custom AuthenticationProvider https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-security/latest/guide/#authenticationProviders